# Create Custom HTTP Header

Tags: messagebroker, extended-sql

I want to deliver a soap message by HTTPS/Post by specifying Content-Type `application/HTTPstream` and the following custom HTTP-headers

```
datatype = 'XML' userid= password
```

I tried with `CALL CopyMessageHeaders();`

```
SET OutputRoot.HTTPRequestHeader."Content-Type" = 'application/HTTPstream';
```

and other part same as this but I am not getting Headers in my output message

Comment: Please answer If any one can help

Comment: Which output node are you using?

Comment: I have written my code CALL CopyMessageHeaders();

SET OutputRoot.HTTPRequestHeader."Content-Type" = 'application/HTTPstream';  in compute node and connected it to http reruest node . I want to see weather http headers are set to my message or not , for that I connected one mq/output node to compute node , There I am supposed to get the output going through that node. But its not reflecting http header part

Comment: But the MQOutput node doesn't care about HTTP headers, so you shouldn't really see those there. To see the HTTP output try using some network monitoring tool, like Fiddler or Wireshark.

Comment: And by the way, just because you include that HTTPstream header, IIB won't support streaming the HTTP output. What do you expect to achieve by adding that header?

Comment: MY Requirement is to code for                                                               "The SOAP message is then delivered by HTTPS/POST to URL by specifying Content-Type ‘application/HTTPstream' and the following custom HTTP-headers actionrequest = ‘upload’ , datatype = ‘XML’ , snrf = (empty) , I exactly dont have an idea how to code for this and check weather it is working or not, Please do suggest how I need to proceed or what I need to refer for my benifits.

Comment: Hi, Attila please provide some solution or something which I can refer for     ( MY Requirement is to code for "The SOAP message is then delivered by HTTPS/POST to URL by specifying Content-Type ‘application/HTTPstream' and the following custom HTTP-headers actionrequest = ‘upload’ , datatype = ‘XML’ , snrf = (empty) , I exactly dont have an idea how to code for this and check weather it is working or not, Please do suggest how I need to proceed or what I need to refer for my benifits.)

Comment: Without you providing some more detailed description of the problem I cannot really help other than to set HTTP headers via the HTTPRequestHeader folder you need to use the HTTPRequest output node. And to check what IIB is sending use a testing tool like SOAPUI, or some HTTP proxy/network monitor like Fiddler or Wireshark.

Comment: Thank you Attila, I used http header node, now I am getting http header part , But I have one doubt weather Content-Type = ‘application/HTTPstream' is header or I need to configure it in http Request node. Thanks for your reply and help